# I have two matrix norms, the first grows, what happens with the other one?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have a matrix A, and two matrix norms: || . ||_alpha and || . ||_beta.
I know that if I change A to A' then ||A||_alpha  < ||A'||_alpha

My question is, in this case, is this true if I use ||.||_beta instead of
||.||_alpha ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not true.

At best, what you know is that both norms are equivalent, that is there exist constants $s>0$ and $t>0$ such that $$s\|.\|_\alpha  \leq \|.\|_\beta\leq t\|.\|_\alpha$$
This is a consequence of those norms being over finite-dimensional vector spaces.
But you can't expect any monotonicity.

Comment: Thank you! And what about the limit and convergence? That is if I have the series A_0, A_1, A_2.... and the lim_{i->inf}||A_i||_alpha is infinity, can I say the same with ||.||_beta? And if the limit with ||A_i||_alpha is finite, is the same true with ||.||_beta? This is the last question, I promise :)

Comment: No problem. If you look at the double inequality in my response (norm equivalence), you'll see that limits are the same (infinite or finite) for both norms.

Comment: Thank you very much!